# Mongodb multiple refrence to same field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I want to use refrence of multipe collection on the same field of mongodb mongoose schema. Is this possible?? All I want is to save object id of different collection in same field,I am doing this,but its not working correctly..

```js
var QuizSchema = new Schema({
 
 
 goal_id:{
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Exam'||'Subject',
 }

});
```

here its save data properly..but when I use populate method it returns null value for document which has ref to second collection ie. Subject

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are able to register a reference to both Models, how do you think Mongoose will be able to populate it?

Instead, you can simply have references to both:

```
var QuizSchema = new Schema({

    goal:{
        exam: {type:ObjectId, ref:'Exam'},
        subject: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Subject'}
    }
});
```

This will even make it convenient to read after population.